# C++11: () or {} in List-initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization, list-initialization

I am referring to "[The working draft N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)", which [is said most similar to the published C++11 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11).

If there are matchable constructors, then it call constructors.

```
Example (p200):
struct S {
    // no initializer-list constructors
    S(int, double, double); // #1
    S(); // #2
    // ...
};

S s1 = { 1, 2, 3.0 }; // OK: invoke #1
S s2 { 1.0, 2, 3 }; // error: narrowing
```

Otherwise, it will use aggregate initialization.

Now, [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#init-list) is an example using `vector`, which has an explicit constructor from `size_t` and an `initializer_list` constructor:

```
vector<double> v1(7);   // ok: v1 has 7 elements
vector<double> v1{7};   // ok: v1 has 1 element (with its value 7.0)
```

Here I am confused. Why is there different behavior for the `vector` constructors than there was for `S`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `initializer_list` overload is strongly preferred to all the other ones. From [over.match.list]:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor
>   in two phases:
>
> (1.1) — Initially, the candidate functions are the *initializer-list* constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the
>   argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
>   (1.2) — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the
>   candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements
>   of the initializer list.

[`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is a non-aggregate class, which has two relevant constructors:

```
explicit vector( size_type count );           // (3)
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,        // (7)
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Based on the ordering described in [over.match.best], since (7) is a viable constructor candidate, we don't get to point (1.2) where (3) would be considered.

Comment: thanks. Now I find in declaration, () cannot work, only {} can work.

Comment: @user1914692 Please don't change your question to ask a different question. If you have a new question, ask a new question.